# Accessing Android activity object during app startup - Nativescript

Tags: nativescript

Before I upgraded to NS 3.4, I used to call the following function in the app start-page's navigatingTo method

`application.android.foregroundActivity.getResources()`

But looks like now in 3.4 - foregroundActivity is undefined - at least while the app is starting up.

Is there an alternate solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
application.android.startActivity
```

However, there was a discussion about the changes in `foregroundActivity` and `startActivity` and the updated information about how those will react in the upcoming NativeScript can be found in [this thread](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5307)

Comment: Thanks. But there were enough breaking changes in 3.4 - that made me revert back to 3.3 - also in conjunction with required newer versions of plugins that also broke the build process.

Comment: I agree with the breaking changes remark -the `foregroundActivity` one is about to be reverted to its default behavior for that very reason - keep an eye on the linked issue